# How to determine if GLM quadratic term should be set up orthogonal or non-orthogonal

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, fitting, polynomial

I am setting up a GLM in R where I have only one predictor variable and its quadratic form. I understand that in R I have 2 options.

```
glm(y~x+I(x^2), family = gaussian) # non-orthogonal polynomial
glm(y~poly(x,2), family = gaussian) # orthogonal
```

How do I determine the best way of fitting the data? Is there a preferred choice because `x^2` is correlated to `x`, and what are its implications?

All the variables involved are continuous, `x` is temperature and `y` is length and each sample has a unique pair `(x,y)`.

Comment: What is the purpose of this GLM?  Prediction of future values?  Interpretation of the coefficients?  Something else?  (The answer depends on the purpose: for instance, if prediction is the only concern, both models are perfectly equivalent, so there is little to choose among them.)

Comment: @whuber I want to find if temperature drives length and if there is any relationship that at certain temperatures I can expect a certain length of a plant/animal. The field is ecology.

Comment: @whuber is there somewhere that explains these concepts?

Comment: @HermanToothrot While this post is a good number of years after yours, it may provide you with some answers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258307/raw-or-orthogonal-polynomial-regression